# Swiper.js - Unbind touchmove event on last slide, rebind on touchmove when direction is up

Tags: javascript, mobile, touch, swiper.js

I have some content below a Swiper.js element. I'm trying to unbind the touchmove event on the slider so that on mobile, users can freely scroll down the page once they are on the last slide of the deck.

Then, when they are at or near the top of the page, or when the top of the swiper element is equal to when window.pageYOffset is 0, rebind the touch event. I am detecting scroll direction so that this event possibly only needs to happen when the direction is going up.

Swiper provides a callback `onReadEnd` that should prove useful.

**Edit**: Provided from the API also are `onTouchMove` and `onTouchMoveOpposite`

#### Relevant Links

- [Swiper.js API Docs](http://idangero.us/swiper/api/)
- [CodePen](http://codepen.io/zizzo/pen/VjgLGK)
- [CodePen - DEBUG MODE](http://s.codepen.io/zizzo/debug/VjgLGK)

To properly debug, use the debug mode link and use dev tools in mobile emulator, refrain from using mousewheel, only click-to-drag to simulate touch events.

I have made the swiper container 80% height for the purposes of debugging - in production it will be 100% viewport height.

Feel free to use jQuery in the solution, it's included in the project already.

### HTML

```
<div id="swiper" class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Header 1</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias totam vero fuga dolorum explicabo suscipit aliquam hic blanditiis soluta officiis, corrupti consequatur nostrum sint possimus neque eos temporibus amet placeat.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias totam vero fuga dolorum explicabo suscipit aliquam hic blanditiis soluta officiis, corrupti consequatur nostrum sint possimus neque eos temporibus amet placeat.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias totam vero fuga dolorum explicabo suscipit aliquam hic blanditiis soluta officiis, corrupti consequatur nostrum sint possimus neque eos temporibus amet placeat.</p>
    <h2>Header 2</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias totam vero fuga dolorum explicabo suscipit aliquam hic blanditiis soluta officiis, corrupti consequatur nostrum sint possimus neque eos temporibus amet placeat.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias totam vero fuga dolorum explicabo suscipit aliquam hic blanditiis soluta officiis, corrupti consequatur nostrum sint possimus neque eos temporibus amet placeat.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias totam vero fuga dolorum explicabo suscipit aliquam hic blanditiis soluta officiis, corrupti consequatur nostrum sint possimus neque eos temporibus amet placeat.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
html, body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color:#000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
}
.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
  background: #fff;

  /* Center slide text vertically */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;

  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.content {
  padding: 30px 15px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

### Javascript

```
var $el = {
  swiper: document.getElementById('swiper')
}

var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
  paginationClickable: true,
  direction: 'vertical',
  onReachEnd: function(swiperInstance) {
    console.log('onReachEnd(), unbind touchmove')
  },
  onTouchMove: function(swiper, event) {
    // Callback function, will be executed when user touch and move finger over Swiper. Receives swiper instance and 'touchmove' event as an arguments.
  },
  onTouchMoveOpposite: function(swiper, event) {
    //  Callback function, will be executed when user touch and move finger over Swiper in direction opposite to direction parameter. Receives swiper instance and 'touchmove' event as an arguments.
  }
});



// Unsure if below will be needed, could be done all within swiper callbacks


var lastY = 0;
$el.swiper.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {
  var currentY = event.touches[0].clientY;
  if ( currentY > lastY ) {
    console.log('up', currentY, lastY)

    // top of page +/- 100px
    // this is inaccurate, currentY is the Y pos of the touch, not
    // equivalent to window.pageYOffset or scrollTop
    if ( currentY <= 100 ) {
      console.log('top of page, rebind touchmove')
    }

  } else if( currentY < lastY ) {
    console.log('down')
  }
  lastY = currentY;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a site where I had a similar situation. You have to set the property `mousewheelControl: true` on initialisation so you can use the methods `.disableMousewheelControl()` and `.enableMousewheelControl()`.

Link to staging site of example: http://multiply.website.2017.360southclients.net:8080/services/seo/

Below is the relevant JS code. (fyi - `freezePoint` calculations take into account the sticky nav bar and `vh`-sized elements above the slideshow)

```
var serviceSwiper = new Swiper( '.swiper-container', {
  direction: 'vertical',
  slidesPerView: 1,
  mousewheelControl: true,
  mousewheelReleaseOnEdges: true,
  mousewheelSensitivity: .05,
  ...
});

serviceSwiper.disableMousewheelControl();

var freezePoint = 0;

$( window ).on( 'resize', function( e ) {
  freezePoint = Math.ceil( $( '#service-slides' ).offset().top - $( '#header' ).outerHeight() - 50 );
}).trigger( 'resize' );

$( window ).on( 'scroll', function( e ) {
  if ( ! serviceSwiper.isEnd && window.scrollY >= freezePoint || ! serviceSwiper.isBeginning && window.scrollY <= freezePoint ) {
    $( 'html' ).scrollTop( freezePoint );
    if ( ! serviceSwiper.params.mousewheelControl ) {
      serviceSwiper.enableMousewheelControl();
    }
  } else if ( serviceSwiper.params.mousewheelControl ) {
    serviceSwiper.disableMousewheelControl();
  }
});
```